# Valums jquery uploader works but returns "Failed"

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload, mkdir

Im trying to setup a page with multiple file uploader sections
anyway it was working fine so far but i have encountered a little problem:

I want a new folder to be created for the files each time an uploader on that page is used.

So i add a `mkdir` command inside the php.php that valums uses to handle the upload procedure.

With that `mkdir` inside the php.php, the folder gets created and files get uploaded so the procedure works...
**BUT** i get a "failed" message next to each filename on the transferlist.

the whole thing works fine without that `mkdir`.

Where should i start looking? any ideas?

here's the code

```
                <script>        
    function createUploader<?php  echo $c; ?>(){            
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('uploadroom<?php  echo $c; ?>'),
            action: '../common/jqueryplugins/valums/server/php.php',
            debug: true,
    // ex. ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'] or []
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
    dragDrop: false,
    params: {
            planid: '<?php  echo $_SESSION['planid']; ?>',
            roomname: 'room<?php  echo $c;   ?>'
        }
        });           
    }


  $(document).ready(function(){createUploader<?php  echo $c; ?>();  });
                </script>
```

i'm getting some variables from php, as this part is being replicated a bunch of times, 
different buttons upload to different folders.

inside the php.php file (at the top) i got something like this:

`$uploaddir = '../../../../rental/userfiles/1/'.$_GET['planid'].'/images/'.$_GET['roomname'].'/';`

`mkdir($uploaddir);`

a weird uploaddir and my mkdir command
and at the end:

```
 `$result = $uploader->handleUpload($uploaddir);`
```

these are mostly the things ive changed
and i get a "failed" next to the filename although it works perfectly

Comment: Post the code with sending and receiving action status.

Comment: I do not know how the js plugin checks the status of downloading, but I think that the server response header. Try to see the status of the response through the firebug console, or something similar.

Comment: here is their whole code: [link](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) the php.php file that handles the most of the work is inside the server folder

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the provided CSS loaded it's going to show failed. By default that span is hidden.